# data output from the database does not work

Tags: php, firebird, firebird2.5

I have an authorization page, it works everything is ok, but when I log in I want to see additional data from the database for this user.
code
    knocks out only one user and everything, when I exit the session and switch on as a new user, nothing is knocked out .... connection to the database works

```
    session_start();

require ('vendor/connect.php');
     $FIRSTNAME=$_SESSION['FIRSTNAME'];

$sql = "SELECT BIRTHDAY from users WHERE FIRSTNAME='$FIRSTNAME'";

$result = ibase_query($db, $sql);

if (ibase_fetch_row($result) > 0) {

    while($row = ibase_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "You BIRTHDAY: " . $row["BIRTHDAY"]. " ";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about sql injection and how to write PHP code to avoid it. The use of `$FIRESTNAME` in `$sql` is a prime example of code that is vulnerable to injection of malicious content that can expose your entire server to those with ill intent.

Comment: What do you mean with "knocks out"?

Comment: im sorry, i mean show

Comment: You might start with providing us REAL DATA you entered into the table and you do enter into the PHP application.  See https://bobby-tables.com/php and also https://www.cqse.eu/en/blog/no-such-thing-as-plain-text/ and https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/

Comment: So probably that other person name, as entered into PHP, is different from what Firebird sees. It might be caused by different character sets, by different escapings (unintended injections for example) and more. I would start with fetching ALL the rows from the table in a loop, and displaying it along with the `$FIRSTNAME` value and along with PHP-made comparison of values in the SQL field and in the variable, does even PHP consider them equal values or not?

Comment: Especially so as it seems plausible you are using Russian codepage or some derived from Russian. And there are very many different charsets that might represent those.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be like below :

```
$sql = "SELECT BIRTHDAY from users WHERE FIRSTNAME='$FIRSTNAME'";
$result = ibase_query($db, $sql);
$row = ibase_fetch_row($result);

while ($row) {
    echo $row[0] . "\t";
}
```

Comment: emmmm/...I think its not correct, because the result is 0 1990-12-10 1990-12-10 1990-12-10 1990-12-10 1990-12-10 1990-12-10 1990-12-10 1990-12-10 1990-12-10 1990-12-10 1990-12-10 1990-12-10 1990-12-10 1990-12-10 1990-12-10 1990-12-10 1990-12-10 1990-12-10 1990-12-10 1990-12-10 1990-12-10 1990-12-10 1990-12-10 1990-12-10 1990-12-10 1990-12-10 1990-12-10 and more

Comment: You're missing a call to `ibase_fetch_row` inside the `while` statement.

Comment: thank you, but it a same problem like the first code, when i log in one person, the birthday is shown but, when I log in with another person, the date isn't shown